# getting the the value of a column at a specific time using Pandas and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been using Pandas for a few weeks so I'm still exploring it.

I have created a DataFrame that is updated hourly at 43 minutes past the hour.
The content of the DF is players stats and I have grouped the content by day of year because I want to know for each day what is the max value in the specific column 'donations'. The value of 'donations' is reset on Sunday at midnight so it will keep growing for the whole week. I would like to have another column in the same DF with the max value at 17.44 everyday.
for now I came up with:

```
originalDF['date']=originalDF['date'].apply(lambda x:
                                        dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
originalDF['DayofYear']=originalDF['date'].dt.dayofyear
highestDonationByTheDay=originalDF.groupby(['DayofYear', 'name']).max()
```

the problem with this is that I don't have control over the time of the day, it just returns the max value of the day that will always be the one at 23.43.

Any help on how to achieve this?

This is an extract of the originalDF:

> ```
> date              donations  A    B     name                C        D
> 2018-04-08 13:43:11    912    192  720    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 13:43:11    785    25   760    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4108
> 2018-04-08 13:43:11    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 13:43:11    915    155  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 13:43:11    1373   613  760    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 14:43:14    922    202  720    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 14:43:14    785    25   760    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4078
> 2018-04-08 14:43:14    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 14:43:14    915    155  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 14:43:14    1373   613  760    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 15:43:15    922    202  720    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 15:43:15    803    43   760    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4108
> 2018-04-08 15:43:15    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 15:43:15    915    155  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 15:43:15    1381   581  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 16:43:13    964    244  720    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 16:43:13    827    47   780    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4108
> 2018-04-08 16:43:13    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 16:43:13    933    173  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 16:43:13    1389   589  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 17:43:17    964    204  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 17:43:17    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4051
> 2018-04-08 17:43:17    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 17:43:17    958    198  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 17:43:17    1439   639  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 18:43:17    984    224  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 18:43:17    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 18:43:17    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 18:43:17    958    198  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 18:43:17    1439   639  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 19:43:14    984    224  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 19:43:14    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 19:43:14    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 19:43:14    958    198  760    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 19:43:14    1441   641  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 20:43:11    984    224  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 20:43:11    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 20:43:11    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 20:43:11    958    158  800    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 20:43:11    1441   641  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 21:43:13    984    224  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 21:43:13    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 21:43:13    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 21:43:13    958    158  800    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 21:43:13    1445   645  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 22:43:13    994    234  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 22:43:13    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 22:43:13    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 22:43:13    958    158  800    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 22:43:13    1445   645  800    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> 2018-04-08 23:43:12    1032   272  760    Eisenheim       80QQVCQ8G   4240
> 2018-04-08 23:43:12    827    27   800    El Mariachi     RUJL8R9Y    4021
> 2018-04-08 23:43:12    690    210  480    macomaco        UJP8LVUL    3980
> 2018-04-08 23:43:12    958    158  800    Skoy            8RLVV20PY   4065
> 2018-04-08 23:43:12    1473   633  840    TheSonicSliver  9LG8QV2G    4207
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for getting the max time before 17.44, you could do this:

```
maxDF = originalDF.set_index('date').between_time('00:00:00', '17:44:00').reset_index()
maxDF['DayofYear'] = maxDF['date'].dt.dayofyear
highestDonationByTheDay = maxDF.groupby(['DayofYear', 'name']).max()
```

Heavily borrowed from:

[Conditional selection before certain time of day - Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41534717/conditional-selection-before-certain-time-of-day-pandas-dataframe)

[Select rows per groups and with time conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680627/select-rows-per-groups-and-with-time-conditions)

Comment: Thank you for your help, especially for the links, very useful.